# Post images printing on default blog page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, blogs

When I add a image with either feature image or advanced costume fields on each blog post but the images also appear on my default blog page (index.php).

So my blog has 4 posts. My default blog page is showing the 4 blog posts it also displays the image set to each blog post.

Here's my in the header that displays the image:

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

$attachment_id = get_field('banner_image');

if( get_field('banner_image') ):

$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'banner' );
?><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="" width ="<?php echo $image[1]?>" height ="<?php echo $image[2]?>" /><?php
        endif;
        endwhile;
        endif;?>
```

And then the code printing all my blog posts in index.php:

```
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="news-artical">

            <?php the_title('<h1>', '</h1>');
            the_excerpt();
            //var_dump($post);
            ?> <hr>
            </div> <?php


     endwhile;
```

Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

All right. The code in your header loops through all displayed posts on each page. If you want to display the image in header only on single post page, you have to wrap it into condition if ( is_single() ) : or if ( is_singular() ) : if you want to display header image also on single page.

```
if ( is_single() && have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

$attachment_id = get_field('banner_image');

if( get_field('banner_image') ):

$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'banner' );
?><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="" width ="<?php echo $image[1]?>" height ="<?php echo $image[2]?>" /><?php
        endif;
        endwhile;
        endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks David, I understand what your saying and i have tried both but it just breaks the image and doesnt show anything at all. Any ideas what this could mean?

Comment: This strips out (breaks) image on your front page, but keep showing images on single post or page (depends on your conditional tag). You want to prevent displaying image on front-page also? Than you have to decide on what image to show. If you want to show image of first or last post listen on front page.